# Syntax Error, unexpected $end -- PHP error, what's wrong?

Tags: php, email, authentication, syntax-error, registration

My entire error code is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/a3704125/public_html/home.php on line 356`

Here is my entire PHP file.. Tell me what the problem may be? ._. Thanks!

```
 <?php

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';
// Those two files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined


session_name('GamesFXLogin');
// Starting the session

session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
// Making the cookie live for 2 weeks

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['GamesFXRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    // If you are logged in, but you don't have the GamesFXRemember cookie (browser restart)
    // and you have not checked the rememberMe checkbox:

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    // Destroy the session
}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: home.php?logout=true");
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

    $err = array();
    // Will hold our errors


    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM gamesfx_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Store some data in the session

            setcookie('GamesFXRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Save the error messages in the session

    header("Location: index.php?page=home&error=true");
    exit;
}
else if($_POST['submit']=='Register')
{
    // If the Register form has been submitted

    $err = array();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 //whether the username is blank
 if($_POST['username'] == '')
 {
  $err[] = 'User Name is required.';
 }
if(strlen($_POST['username'])<4 || strlen($_POST['username'])>32)
    {
        $err[]='Your username must be between 3 and 32 characters!';
    }
if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.]+/i',$_POST['username']))
    {
        $err[]='Your username contains invalid characters!';
    }

 //whether the email is blank
 if($_POST['email'] == '')
 {
  $err[]='E-mail is required.';
 }
 else
 {
  //whether the email format is correct
  if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email']))
  {
   //if it has the correct format whether the email has already exist
   $email= $_POST['email'];
   $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM gamesfx_members WHERE email = '$email'";
   $result1 = mysql_query($link,$sql1) or die(mysql_error());
   if (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0)
            {
    $err[]='This Email is already used.';
   }
  }
  else
  {
   //this error will set if the email format is not correct
   $err[]='Your email is not valid.';
  }
 }
 //whether the password is blank
 if($_POST['password'] == '')
 {
  $err[]='Password is required.';
 }  
    if(!count($err))
    {
        // If there are no errors

// Make sure the email address is available:
        if(!count($err))
    {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $activation = md5(uniqid(rand()));
  $encrypted=md5($password);

  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO gamesfx_members (usr, email, pass, Activate) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$encrypted', '$activation')";
  $result2 = mysql_query($link,$sql2) or die(mysql_error());

  if($result2)
  {
   $to = $email;
   $subject = "Confirmation from GamesFX to $username";
   $header = "GamesFX: Confirmation from GamesFX";
   $message = "Please click the link below to verify and activate your account. rn";
   $message .= "http://www.mysite.com/activate.php?key=$activation";

   $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

   if($sentmail)
            {
   echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
   }
   else
         {
    echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
   }
  }
exit();
 }
}

$script = '';

if($_SESSION['msg'])
{
    // The script below shows the sliding panel on page load

    $script = '
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){

            $("div#panel").show();
            $("#toggle a").toggle();
        });

    </script>';

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>A Cool Login System With PHP MySQL &amp jQuery | Tutorialzine demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slide.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- PNG FIX for IE6 -->
    <!-- http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6 -->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pngfix/supersleight-min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="js/slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <?php echo $script; ?>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Panel -->
<div id="toppanel">
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="left">
                <h1>The Sliding jQuery Panel</h1>
                <h2>A register/login solution</h2>      
                <p class="grey">You are free to use this login and registration system in you sites!</p>
                <h2>A Big Thanks</h2>
                <p class="grey">This tutorial was built on top of <a href="http://web-kreation.com/index.php/tutorials/nice-clean-sliding-login-panel-built-with-jquery" title="Go to site">Web-Kreation</a>'s amazing sliding panel.</p>
            </div>


            <?php

            if(!$_SESSION['id']):

            ?>

            <div class="left">
                <!-- Login Form -->
                <form class="clearfix" action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Member Login</h1>

                    <?php

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['login-err'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
                        }
                    ?>

                    <label class="grey" for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="password" name="password" id="password" size="23" />
                    <label><input name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="bt_login" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="left right">            
                <!-- Register Form -->
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Not a member yet? Sign Up!</h1>     

                    <?php

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err']);
                        }

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']);
                        }
                    ?>

                    <label class="grey" for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="email" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="password" name="password" id="password" size="30" />
                    <label>A password will be e-mailed to you.</label>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="bt_register" />
                </form>
            </div>

            <?php

            else:

            ?>

            <div class="left">

            <h1>Members panel</h1>

            <p>You can put member-only data here</p>
            <a href="index.php?page=profile">View your profile information and edit it</a>
            <p>- or -</p>
            <a href="?logoff">Log off</a>

            </div>

            <div class="left right">
            </div>

            <?php
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /login -->  

    <!-- The tab on top --> 
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="login">
            <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['usr'] ? $_SESSION['usr'] : 'Guest';?>!</li>
            <li class="sep">|</li>
            <li id="toggle">
                <a id="open" class="open" href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['id']?'Open Panel':'Log In | Register';?></a>
                <a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close" href="#">Close Panel</a>         
            </li>
            <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul> 
    </div> <!-- / top -->

</div> <!--panel -->
```

I am trying to use the slide panel that's a login panel.. Don't know if you ever heard of it. But anyhow, I am wondering how to fix this error. As-for I can't see what the problem may be.. I'm banging my head over it, thanks for the help!

EDIT: I added what's after the  below this text..

```
<div class="pageContent">
    <div id="main">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>A Cool Login System</h1>
        <h2>Easy registration management with PHP &amp; jQuery</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="container">

          <p>This is a simple example site demonstrating the <a href="http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/">Cool Login System tutorial</a> on <strong>Tutorialzine</strong>. You can start by clicking the <strong>Log In | Register</strong> button above.  After registration, an email will be sent to you with your new password.</p>
          <p><a href="registered.php" target="_blank">View a test page</a>, only accessible by <strong>registered users</strong>.</p>
          <p>The sliding jQuery panel, used in this example, was developed by  <a href="http://web-kreation.com/index.php/tutorials/nice-clean-sliding-login-panel-built-with-jquery" title="Go to site">Web-Kreation</a>.</p>
          <p>You are free to build upon this code and use it in your own sites.</p>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

      <div class="container tutorial-info">
      This is a tutorialzine demo. View the <a href="http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/" target="_blank">original tutorial</a>, or download the <a href="demo.zip">source files</a>.    </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: </html> is on line 356.

Comment: Keep your code formatted and good indented.

Comment: really such a horrible code ... and md5 for password isnt safe any more use bycript instead ..

Comment: Try to keep your PHP code separated from your HTML coding. You can obey OOP style for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing brackets in here :

```
else if($_POST['submit']=='Register')
{
```

Put two closing brackets here:

```
$script = '';
}}                              #line 175
if($_SESSION['msg'])
```

Moral: always put `opening and closing` brackets together when going for any condition statement.

Comment: By closing brackets you mean what exactly? Sorry, a bit new to the technical terms.. But can identify it once I see what you mean.

Comment: See above, for the solution.